# How to make multiple DNS point to one service in Kubernetes

Tags: dns, kubernetes, docker-compose

When we were using `docker-compose`, we could map multiple aliases to one container/service via `links`. For example, `bucket1.s3` and `bucket2.s3` are aliases for container `s3`. Now as we are moving to kubernetes, I'm trying to do the same and link containers using service discovery.

What I can think of right now is to have one service for each bucket and each service will point to the same pod. This seems a lot of work. Is there way to make multiple DNS mapped to one service so `bucket1.s3.namespace.svc.cluster.local` and `bucket2.s3.namespace.svc.cluster.local` can both be resolved to `s3` service?

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you might want is one service mapped to two deployments, you could have two [deployments](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) with names bucket1 and bucket2 and have them labeled with one label `app: buckets` then have a service with a selector including that label.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: bucket1
  labels:
    app: buckets
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: buckets
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: buckets
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: bucket-container
        image: bucketimage
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

---

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: bucket2
  labels:
    app: buckets
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: buckets
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: buckets
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: bucket-container
        image: bucketimage
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

---

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: s3
spec:
  selector:
    app: buckets
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
```

But a further question would be why would you want to have that? if both bucket1 and bucket2 contain different information/data.

With Kubernetes generally, you would have one deployment with multiple pods/replicas to serve data either in bucket1 or bucket2 assuming the data is the same. If the data is different why not have 2 deployments with different DNS entries.

If you are using K8s 1.11 or later, you can also [tweak the coredns `ConfigMap`](https://coredns.io/2017/05/08/custom-dns-entries-for-kubernetes/) in the `kube-system` namespace to possibly get what you are trying to get to but in terms of DNS [you can't have a single record map to two CNAMEs](https://serverfault.com/questions/574072/can-we-have-multiple-cnames-for-a-single-name) as per RFC 1034, Section 3.6.2.  You can't also hardcode IPs in Kubernetes since your IPs always change when your pods get created/removed.

Comment: Yes, bucket1 and bucket2 would have different data. So in this case, the right approach is to tweak coredns if the k8s version is 1.11 or later?

Comment: If your version is as @Rico stated, 1.11 or later then yes, use the Custom DNS entries.